# Acessing inline-controller variable from directive template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a fiddle representing my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/m9t7ew8j/1/

The essential part of the code that matters is the following:

```
   .directive('firstDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div>This is a directive.
                        Here is a scope variable
                        pre-defined: {{name}} </div>', // <---- this is the problem
            controller: ['$q', function ($q) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.name = 'something';
            }]
        }
    }])
```

Basically, the controller has no name because it's an inline-controller, so how do I represent it in the template attribute? Do I have to actually declare the controller like the following?

```
    .controller('secondController', [function(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = 'John Snow';
    }])
    .directive('secondDirective', [function(){
        return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>This is a directive.
                   Here is a scope variable
                   pre-defined: {{vm.name}} </div>', // <- declaring as vm.name will work
        controller: 'secondController as vm'
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your controller you want to get the `$scope` and assign the variable to `$scope`.

```
.directive('firstDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div>This is a directive.
                        Here is a scope variable
                        pre-defined: {{name}} </div>',
            controller: ['$scope','$q', function ($scope,$q) {
                $scope.name = 'something';
            }]
        }
    }])
```

demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/uzudOphRL8QO6utEBF4F?p=preview

From achieving using `this`

```
.directive('firstDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div>This is a directive.
                        Here is a scope variable
                        pre-defined: {{vm.name}} </div>',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            controller: ['$q', function ($q) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.name = 'something';
            }]
        }
    }])
```

Comment: No way to do this using `this` instead of `$scope`?